# Mongoose auto increment for existing collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have an existing collection named `users` with the following schema. I want to add a new auto incremented field named `userNumber` in it. I have seen the [counter](https://intellipaat.com/community/44987/mongoose-auto-increment) based solution but failed to implement those mainly because I don't see the working where it will do the numbering for the existing documents plus where to place that code. So my question is how to add `userNumber` field with auto incrementing values and how to populate values for this column in existing records

**user.model**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    userType: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
    },
    uid: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
    },
    firstName: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    lastName: {
      type: String,
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      lowercase: true,
    },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

Answer (score 0):

First you can add  userNumber to your User schema and when you want to create new user then add value to userNumber automatically by get old value from database and incremented.

Comment: yeah, I get that but what about existing documents

Comment: You have old documents already on production?

Comment: Ok you can updated all documents by runing a function got through all documents and update by add userNumber

Answer (score 0):

here is how it works with counter:

```
export const CounterSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  _id: {type: String, required: true},
  seq: {type: Number, default: 0}
},
```

the `_id` could be anything you want. In that case i would name it `user`

the `seq` (sequence) is your current count, starting at 0.

to update the counter you will have to call it every time you create a new user.

```
const callBack: MongooseDocument = await counterModel.findOneAndUpdate({_id: 
'user'}, {$inc: {seq: 1}}, {new: true});
```

to access the new count you call:  `newCount = callBack.toJSON().seq`

to make it work for you current situation, you will have to loop through your users and update them one by one. When that is done, you update your counter and after that you do it whenever you create a user..